# UTC String in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I want to get a string in this pattern:

2015-11-17T17:34:01Z

```
moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss");
```

I tried every method, and all the time, the 'T' is cutted, and I get this result:
"12/29/2015 14:08:43"

If I'll replace the T with another letter it will work. I even tried to replace a K letter with a T, but it's the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: just tried and it output `2015-12-29T14:22:47`

Comment: Also seems odd that you're reporting you're getting the result with m/d/y format rather than y-m-d - how exactly are you displaying/manipulating the output?

Comment: moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss").replace(" ","T")

Comment: just calling moment().utc().format() - should give you iso date format.

Comment: @user3712353 Judging by the "last seen" on your profile, you asked this question then disappeared.  Please be aware of just how active Stack Overflow is - it's usually worthwhile hanging around after asking a question to see if there are any follow up comments such as those above.

Answer (score 3):

you mean you want iso format ?

```
moment().toISOString();
```

even native date has it

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

Comment: Just heading that way myself... [here's the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/).

Comment: And if it doesn't then [`es5-shim`](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) will add it to the native.